# How to REPLACE a specific word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE TESTDE(
Query VARCHAR(150)
);

INSERT INTO TESTDE VALUES ('SELECT EmployeeName FROM EmployeeTable WHERE FirstName = ''Asim'' AND LastName = ''Asghar'' AND EducationLevel = ''School''');


SELECT * FROM TESTDE
SELECT REPLACE(Query, '=', '<>') FROM TESTDE
```

I have this table and a query stored in it. I want to replace only specific word with something from this query saved.
For instance my requirement is to replace `=` with `<>` only which is after `EducationLevel`. I have query but it replaces all `=` with `<>`.

Comment: Why are you storing queries?

Comment: How do you handle tokenizing, e.g. if you want to change `=` to `<>` you probably don't want to change `!=` to `!<>`? Similarly, changing `car` to `truck` probably shouldn't change `encarta` to `entrucka`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to replace the `=` that is after `EducationLevel`, you can select it using "EducationLevel =". So your query should be something like:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Query, 'EducationLevel =', 'EducationLevel <>') FROM TESTDE
```